# Is Visual Studio installing Nuget Packages differently?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I am using VS 2022 and .Net Core 6.  When I install a scripted package from Nuget, such as jquery, fontawesome or bootstrap, the package shows up under [Dependencies], but no scripts are installed or updated in wwwroot.  Is there a new way we are supposed to reference these in our html pages or am I dealing with a bug in VS or Nuget?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delete the jquery folder and download it again using [LibMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-6.0).
Then re-add the JQuery reference in the Layout.cshtml in View.